# How to say "Clock drift" in Russian?

Tags: перевод

Source: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3658181/PiotrPiasecki-BitcoinMasterThesis.pdf

Cite:

> 4.5.5 Clock drift
>
> The Standard Client exchanges the current machine time with its peers when establishing new connections. It also
> maintains a counter representing the med ian network time reported by
> the Client's peers. If the counter differs by more than 70 minutes
> than the Node's machine time, it is reset to represent the latter

Methinks, that "Clock drift" means the control of time shifting (to forward or to backward).

Comment: It is _уход часов_

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I googled for "**уход часов**" suggested by jwalker and found a lot of documents. Looks like it is a professional term. Here is a citation from ["Энциклопедия Кругосвет"](http://krugosvet.ru/enc/nauka_i_tehnika/voennaya_tehnika/NAVIGATSIYA.html?page=0,2) about GPS positioning:

> Система основана на вычислении расстояния от пользователя до спутника по измеренному времени от передачи сигнала спутником до приема этого сигнала пользователем. Пользователю не требуется иметь точные часы, поскольку измеряется расстояние до четырех спутников и по данным этих измерений вычисляются не только три координаты, но и **уход часов** пользователя.

[Google Book Search](https://www.google.com.ua/search?tbm=bks&hl=ru&q=%22%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4+%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%22) gives a lot of citations:

> Часы с системой автоподстройки работали с большой стабильностью: среднеквадратическая вариация суточного хода за семь месяцев составила 1*10<sup>-9</sup> с, а **уход часов** за этот же период — 2,8 мс. - Труды Советской антарктической экспедиции, 1978.

Wikipedia article [Долгота](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) uses this (or similar "среднесуточный уход") term several times:

> Для того чтобы определять долготу с такой точностью во время плавания в Вест-Индию, требовались **часы со среднесуточным уходом** не более 3 секунд (при том, что часы в то время считались очень точными, если вообще имели минутную стрелку).
>
> Эти часы были проверены во время двух плаваний в Вест-Индию — в 1761 и 1764 годах, **уход** при этом составил 5 секунд за три месяца путешествия.

Comment: I've also found: `деривация времени` or `девиация времени`. See, https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Деривация and https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Девиация_частоты

Comment: Это явно чей-то очень неудачный перевод. Очень режет слух, поверьте.

Comment: Я про "уход часов". Деривация времени хорошозвучит, хотя, не могу назвать этот термин популярным.

Comment: @Sergei Поищите в гугл букс. Множество примеров из научных и технических книг времен СССР. Это не "чей-то неудачный перевод" а устоявшийся термин.

Comment: @user2496 Не нашел примеров использования деривации времени или девиации времени. Деривация - изменение под влиянием конкретного фактора, например отклонение пули от идеальной траектории из-за вращения пули. Ну да, девиация переводится как "отклонение". Тут встает вопрос - зачем придумывать новые термины - чтобы понаучнее звучало?

Comment: @Artemix, `деривация времени` - is a translate.google.com Think, you are right, `уход часов` - will be better.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is equivalent term in Russian. So you could translate by meaning: `Разница в скорости хода часов`.
Read [clock drift article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_drift) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Да скорость у всех часов одинаковая, просто разные пользователи могут иметь разное время в системных часах компьютера.

Comment: Почитайте статью на вики. Только у [идеальных](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B2_%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5) часов скорость хода одинаковая.

Comment: @Sergei На компьютерные часы влияет множество факторов, в том числе напряжение в сети, состояние батарейки на плате BIOS и т.п. Задачи создать суперточные часы инженеры перед собой не ставили - везде где нужна относительная точность используют сетевые службы времени для регулярной синхроницации компьютерных часов.

Comment: Но здесь идёт речь про то, стоит ли принимать участок цепи биткоин, и если разница во времени превышает 70 часов, то цепочка не принимается. Ну на крайний случай "разница по времени". В скорости не обязательно должна быть разница, хотя в незначительной степени она, вероятно, и есть

Comment: Речь в цитате идет о том, как обрабатывать ситуацию связанную с Clock Drift. Цитата не является определением явления, а способом бороться с ним. Вопрос - как перевести "Clock Drift".

Answer (score 2):

text adapted for bitcoin:

**4.5.5 Погрешность времени**

If the name of the section you want to use as the name of the attack, can be rename to:
**4.5.5 Фальсификация времени**

Falsification in this context combines concepts such as the time is lag and the time is fast.

Злоумышленник может инициировать атаку **фальсификацией времени**, против двух различных узлов[116], путем создания многочисленных вредоносных соединений.

Атака с использованием **фальсификации времени**, может быть использована для облегчения применения двойной атаки (см. 4.5.13), в качестве атакующего. Путем создания альтернативной цепочки блоков, которая будет принята, только атакуемым с **фальсифицированным временем**. В этом случае атакуемому участнику не придется иметь дело с валидной цепочкой блоков.

Если злоумышленник сможет **фальсифицировать отставание времени** от текущего времени участников сети, у первого майнинг пула, а у второго **опережение времени**, атака может привести пулы к невозможности генерации различных блоков, которые могли бы оказаться в цепочке блоков.